# How do I merge multiple sequences in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a list of ordered date for the 3rd of the month, 16 of the month, and every Friday.

It looks like this

```
    B2 - 2002/1/3
    B3 - 2002/1/16
    B4 - 2020/9/11
    =TRANSPOSE(EDATE(B2,SEQUENCE(36,1,0)))
    =TRANSPOSE(EDATE(B3,SEQUENCE(36,1,0,1)))
    =TRANSPOSE((SEQUENCE(144,1,B4,7)))
```

I would like it all to be in on row with unique values only. I tried to use LET but I can't figure our how to have them merged into one list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using LET and CHOOSE:

```
=LET(a,EDATE(B2,SEQUENCE(1,36,0)),
    b,EDATE(B3,SEQUENCE(1,72,-36,1)),
    c,SEQUENCE(1,144+72,B4-(72*7),7),
    d,SEQUENCE(1,144+36+36),
    UNIQUE(SORT(CHOOSE(IF(d<37,1,IF(d<73,2,3)),a,b,c),1,1,TRUE),TRUE))
```

[image]

There is a new function currently on available to Office 365 insiders beta channel HSTACK that would simplify this:

```
=LET(a,EDATE(B2,SEQUENCE(1,36,0)),
    b,EDATE(B3,SEQUENCE(1,36,0,1)),
    c,SEQUENCE(1,144,B4,7),
    UNIQUE(SORT(HSTACK(a,b,c),1,1,TRUE),TRUE))
```

Comment: I like the second formula most, because nice use of `HSTACK()`, and the formula gets smaller as well.

Comment: I don't know why, even if add UNIQUE for December 3, 2021 there is a duplicate value :(

Comment: Where did you add the UNIQUE?

Comment: @FINISHUT also I am not showing a duplicate with the settings in B2:B4, so can you tell me what you have in those cells that created that?

Comment: @FINISHUT See edit.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner, how can I add a gap of one cell between the sequence? so that there will be a date, empty cell, date, empty cell, etc.... Huge thanks!

Comment: That is a new question, please create a new post(you can refer back to this one).  Make sure you have mock data and expected output.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner, how can I add a gap of one cell between the sequence? so that there will be a date, empty cell, date, empty cell, etc.... Huge thanks! my solution for now is to index match the next date, it works but I am relying on the sequence, so I am hiding the sequence and creating a new range with index match =INDEX($N1:$Z1,1,MATCH(O3,$N1:$Z1)+2)

Comment: @FINISHUT see my last comment on how that is a new question.